# Excel VBA error 438 in combo box form validation

Tags: excel, vba

I want to validate page 2 of my MultiPage control. 
It has 2 combo boxes, 2 radio buttons and several text boxes.

Basically, all fields must have a value.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub validaPasso3()
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls
    If cCont.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Error."
        Exit Sub
    End If 
Next
End Sub
```

But this is returning the error:

```
Run-time error: ´438´ Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

On line:

```
If cCont.Value = vbNullString Then
```

I know this caused by the 1st combo box.

What is causing the error?

Comment: What particular control is it that doesn't have this `.Value` property?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is selected in a combobox, it will return `Null` rather than `vbNullString`. You could use something like this instead:

```
Private Sub validaPasso3()
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls
    If Typename(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
        If IsNull(cCont.Value) Then 
            MsgBox "Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf Typename(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
        If cCont.Value = vbNullString Then
            Msgbox "Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf Typename(cCont) = "OptionButton" Then
        If cCont.Value = False Then
            MsgBox "Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems to work well except for the option buttons. They're asking a Yes/No question so one of them will always be empty. With the code above, the validation passes only if all the fields are filled in.

Comment: For clarification as to the OP's question _What is causing the error?_ The data type `Control` does not have the `.value`. It's more like a container for the controls. Each control has it's own set of methods to get the value or property associated with the control.

Comment: @NunoNogueira No probs. You may need to put some 'manually' logic in to determine if one of the option buttons in a group is selected or not.